# 'error: variable has incomplete type' problem with linking

Tags: c, makefile, building

I'm having problems building a very basic project. The compiler seems to think that I have not defined a certain type, even though the type is definitely defined. When I run `make`, I get the following error:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c11   -c -o set.o set.c
gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c11   -c -o driver.o driver.c
driver.c:12:9: error: variable has incomplete type 'set_t' (aka 'struct set')
  set_t hey;
        ^
./set.h:10:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct set'
typedef struct set set_t;
               ^
1 error generated.
```

Here's my makefile:

```
# Makefile for groups

PROG = driver
HEADERS = set.h
OBJS = driver.o set.o

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -std=c11

$(PROG): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

driver.o: set.h set.o
set.o: set.h

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

driver.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "set.h"

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  set_t hey;

  return 0;
}
```

set.h:

```c
#ifndef __SET_H
#define __SET_H

typedef struct set set_t;

set_t* set_new();

#endif
```

set.c:

```c
#include "set.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct set {
  int size;
  void** items;
} set_t;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: your `typedef struct set {...} set_t` should be in your header file.

Comment: Why'd you say it's a problem with linking? The error you're getting is from the compiler, not the linker.

Comment: The error message is a compiler not a linker error, and it is reported for line 12 of driver.c, you fragment has only 9 lines - so this error does not even relate to this code.  You will get the error if you access members of the forward declared `set_t`, this code does not do that.  Only code in set.c has visibility of the members of `set_t`.

Answer (score 2):

As you probably know, #including headers pretty much means copy-pasting the whole file.

Let's see what happens to `driver.c` if we copy-paste `set.h`:

driver.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef __SET_H
#define __SET_H

typedef struct set set_t;

set_t* set_new();

#endif

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  set_t hey;

  return 0;
}
```

Now that we got that out of the way, let's focus on this line:

```
typedef struct set set_t;
```

This aliases type `struct set` as `set_t`, but, since `struct set` wasn't encountered in the code before, it also acts as a forward-declaration. Let's make that declaration a bit more obvious:

```
struct set;
typedef struct set set_t;
```

What does a forward-declaration allow us to do? Take pointers to the structure in question. What does it not allow us to do? Create objects of that type. We can see this is exactly what we are trying to do in `main`:

```
set_t hey; //attempting to create a new object, but fails because the compiler doesn't have all the necessary information about the structure
//the compiler only knows that the structure exists
```

Whenever you are declaring structs, you declare the whole struct in the header file, along with all the typedefs and function prototypes. The .c file should only contain the definition of those functions. Let's correct your code:

driver.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "set.h"

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  set_t hey;

  return 0;
}
```

set.h:

```
#ifndef __SET_H
#define __SET_H

typedef struct set {
  int size;
  void** items;
} set_t;

set_t* set_new();

#endif
```

set.c:

```
#include "set.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

//place all the definitions of the functions here, like that set_new() function
```

Answer (score 0):

your example:
#ifndef #ifndef __SET_H
#define __SET_H
...
#endif
suppose   __SET_H was defined before the #include ... where you
thought set was defined.  You would have this symptom.
#pragma once works just fine.  I evolve data types by copying .h files
including their guard words.  You get .h files that can't include each other.